# Send HTML Content to email client (Gmail) using ShareCompat.IntentBuilder

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to send an email which is HTML formatted. I have been trying with the following code with no luck

```
    val body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\" target=\"_blank\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></body></html>"

    ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            //.setType("message/rfc822")
            .setType("text/html")
            .setSubject("test")
            .setHtmlText(body) 
            .setChooserTitle("Send Email")
            .startChooser()
```

Its just not working...coming as plain text.

Comment: Try simplifying the HTML, such as removing `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Beyond that, what does "coming as plain text" mean, exactly? Is the email client showing plain text? Is the email client showing formatted text, but the email recipient is seeing plain text? Something else?